# OutputCache directive not working in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, html, http, caching

I added an outputcache directive to my asp.net page (asp.net 4.0) as such:

```
        <%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" Location="Client" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

However, this does not appear to be working.  When I check the http header information I see this:

```
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
        Cache-Control => no-cache, no-store
        Pragma => no-cache
        Content-Type => text/html; charset=utf-8
        Expires => -1
        Server => Microsoft-IIS/7.0
        X-AspNet-Version => 4.0.30319
        Set-Cookie => ASP.NET_SessionId=0txhgxrykz5atrc3a42lurn1; path=/; HttpOnly
        X-Powered-By => ASP.NET
        Date => Tue, 15 Nov 2011 20:47:28 GMT
        Connection => close
        Content-Length => 17428
```

The above shows that the OutputCache directive was not applied.  I even tried this from codebehind:

```
        this.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1.0));
        TimeSpan ds = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0);
        this.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(ds);
```

The above code should have the same results as the OutputCache directive, but when I check the http header information, I can see it's still not being applied.

Basically, the purpose here is to make sure that when a user clicks the back button and lands on my page, the page will not be retrieved from the server.  I want to avoid getting the browser popup that asks the user to 'resend.'  I want the browser to just use the copy of the page it has in it's cache.

Thanks in advace for any help.

Comment: That browser popup has nothing to do with cache...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question:

> I want to avoid getting the browser popup that asks the user to
> 'resend.' I want the browser to just use the copy of the page it has
> in it's cache.

If browser asks you to resend data, it means that content was response to POST request.

According to [RFC 2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html):

> Some HTTP methods MUST cause a cache to invalidate an entity. This is
> either the entity referred to by the Request-URI, or by the Location
> or Content-Location headers (if present). These methods are:
>
> - PUT
> - DELETE
> - POST

So, to make cache work, you need to convert your POST to GET.